# Remove "\" when we add as a value to dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have to add value for a key in a dictionary the value is JSON string but it should not have "\" or "\n" in the value,

I tried to remove them and created a string to set the value for key in dictionary but when i add the value to key it automatically adds "\" but when i check the string "\" are not there.

Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue

Value(Json String): Need to set for "CartProducts" Key in the dictionary

```
[{"type":"radio","product_option_value_id":"633","value":"Medium(40c)","option_value_id":"49","product_option_id":"49","option_id":"56","name":"Medium(40c)"}] 

dictionary {
    account = guest;
    CartProducts = "[{\"product_id\":\"56\",\"option\":\"[{\"type\":\"radio\",\"product_option_value_id\":\"633\",\"value\":\"Medium(40c)\",\"option_value_id\":\"49\",\"product_option_id\":\"49\",\"option_id\":\"56\",\"name\":\"Medium(40c)\"}]\",\"quantity\":\"1\",\"category\":\"Cappuccino\",\"price\":\"3.90\",\"model\":\"Coffee\",\"delivery_date\":\"2016-04-2006:00:01+0000\",\"total\":\"3.90\",\"name\":\"Cappuccino\"}]";
}
```

Need to remove "\" from the key "CartProducts"  in the dictionary "dictionary"

Comment: Are you sure that the backslashes really exist? And to avoid linefeed characters remove any `pretty print` option when the JSON is going to be created.

Answer (score 0):

\" in this case is an escape character. It is used to distinguish quotes within quotes.

Take an example:

```
Product = "my example variable = "hello""
```

the quotes in this case clashes. To the compiler it looks like

```
Product = "my example variable = "

//Ouside quotes 
hello

//empty quotes at the end
""
```

Basically it is a mess. So the work around is to use \" which is treated as a single character but is considered part of the string as ".

Other example of escape characters:

```
 \'    single quote '
 \n   new line
 \t    tab
 \\    backslash \
```

Comment: how to use it in the above question, I think it wont work for the this case